# configuration on wampp to accept innodb does not work

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, wamp

I want my wamp accepts mysql innodb, for it i made ​​the following configuration in my.ini:

```
# Example MySQL config file for medium systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (32M - 64M) where MySQL plays
# an important part, or systems up to 128M where MySQL is used together with
# other programs (such as a web server)
#
# You can copy this file to
# /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is C:\mysql\data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.16
log-error=c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log
datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.16/data

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
#skip-networking

# Disable Federated by default
skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
log-bin=mysql-bin

# binary logging format - mixed recommended
binlog_format=mixed

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir     = /tmp/     
#log-update     = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
innodb_data_home_dir = C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\data
innodb_data_file_path = C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\data
#ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\data
innodb_log_arch_dir = C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\data
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld]
port=3306
```

and the wamp's figure does not become green ... only orange

here folows the mysql error reporting:

```
111011 16:18:50 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
111011 16:18:50 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
111011 16:18:51 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
111011 16:18:51 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
111011 16:18:51 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
111011 16:18:51 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
111011 16:18:51 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
111011 16:18:51  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
111011 16:18:52 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
111011 16:18:52 [ERROR] wampmysqld: unknown variable 'innodb_log_arch_dir=C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.16/data'
111011 16:18:52 [ERROR] Aborting

111011 16:18:52  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
111011 16:18:52  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
111011 16:18:52 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

111011 16:21:08 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
111011 16:21:08 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
111011 16:21:08 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
111011 16:21:08 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
111011 16:21:08 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
111011 16:21:08 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
111011 16:21:08 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
111011 16:21:09  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
111011 16:21:10 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
111011 16:21:10 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
111011 16:21:10 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.16-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
111011 16:29:42 [Note] wampmysqld: Normal shutdown

111011 16:29:42 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
111011 16:29:42  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
111011 16:29:42  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
111011 16:29:43 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

111011 16:29:43 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
111011 16:29:43 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
111011 16:29:43 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
111011 16:29:43 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
111011 16:29:43 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
111011 16:29:43 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
111011 16:29:43  InnoDB: Operating system error number 123 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File name C:\wampin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\data\ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
111011 16:33:50 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
111011 16:33:50 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
111011 16:33:50 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
111011 16:33:50 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
111011 16:33:50 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
111011 16:33:50 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
111011 16:33:50  InnoDB: Operating system error number 123 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File name C:\wampin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\data\ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
111011 16:34:32 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
111011 16:34:32 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
111011 16:34:32 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
111011 16:34:32 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
111011 16:34:32 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
111011 16:34:32 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
111011 16:34:32  InnoDB: Operating system error number 123 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File name C:\wampin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\data\ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
111011 16:37:29 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
111011 16:37:29 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
111011 16:37:29 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
111011 16:37:29 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
111011 16:37:29 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
111011 16:37:29 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
111011 16:37:29  InnoDB: Operating system error number 123 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File name C:\wampin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\data\ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
111011 16:38:07 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
111011 16:38:07 [ERROR] InnoDB: syntax error in innodb_data_file_path
111011 16:38:07 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
111011 16:38:07 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
111011 16:38:07 [ERROR] wampmysqld: unknown variable 'innodb_log_arch_dir=C:\wampin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\data'
111011 16:38:07 [ERROR] Aborting

111011 16:38:07 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

111011 16:38:43 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
111011 16:38:43 [ERROR] InnoDB: syntax error in innodb_data_file_path
111011 16:38:43 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
111011 16:38:43 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
111011 16:38:43 [ERROR] wampmysqld: unknown variable 'innodb_log_arch_dir=C:\wampin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\data'
111011 16:38:43 [ERROR] Aborting

111011 16:38:43 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Anyone know how can I fix it? or if I have to configure anything else ?

tanks... for helping...

Comment: Inno-setup and innodb are two completely different products. I've retagged to suit.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
innodb_log_arch_dir=C:\wampin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\data
```

seems to have a broken path. Try using slashes (/) instead of backslashes (). It should be `c:\wamp\bin`.